# How to architect job scheduler

Tags: cron, architecture, rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices

I am building a job scheduler and I am stuck between two approaches. I have two types of jobs, ones that are scheduled for a specific date and ones that run hourly. For the specific date ones, I poll my database table that stores the jobs and post the results to a rabbitmq message broker where specific workers process them. This works well for more defined tasks like sending reminder notifications or emails. For the hourly jobs, I have a cron expression based job running and have the logic directly in the function, so it does not go to a queue. Usually, these are jobs to clean up my database or set certain values based on previous day activity, etc.

I am wondering what the best way to architect this is. Does it make sense to have all these smaller jobs running on a cadence as microservices and listen on a queue? Should I group all of them together into one service? Should I combine all logic of both types into one large worker app?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion as described you have two different systems that are doing two different things and this is a problem.

For example consider sending an email.  With the design you have right now you have to write your email code twice -- once for messages that are sent to the queue and once for the ones sent from the cron.

Ideally you want to make supporting the system in your design as easy as possible.  For example if your design uses a queue then ALL actions should work the same way -- get a command message and parameters off the queue and execute them.  Your cron job and your scheduler would both add messages to the queue.  Supporting a new action would just mean coding it once and then both systems could add a message to the queue.

The same should be true of your data model.  The data model should support both types of schedule but share as much as possible.

---

The last time I created a system like this I did something along the following lines:

I had an events table -- this table had a list of events to fire are specific dates and times in the future..

I had a retur table -- this table had a list of recurring events (eg every week on a tuesday at this time.)

There was a process -- it would look at the events table to see if there was something that needed to fire.  If there was it would fire it.  THEN it would remove it from the events table (no longer in the future) and log it had been run.  It would also check if this was a event from the recur table -- if it was it would add the next future event to the events table.

Note, this design only has two tables here in this simplified explanation of how the events table worked, but in reality there were a number of others in the complete data model.  For example I had a number of tables to support different event types.  (Email templates for the email events, etc).

Comment: Right so I am consolidating it, meaning I am going to have repeating jobs in my jobs table and just have a single cron job to poll the table and upload the job to the queue. Main question is around the workers that will receive those messages. I don't think it makes a ton of sense to spin up an entire service to do a v small job like update a field in a db at 10pm every night.

Comment: @joethemow -- I describe how mine worked above -- does this answer your question?

Comment: Kind of. So I understand what you are saying but my question is more around how to separate/consolidate certain workers. Like I might have a worker app just for sending out alerts or long lasting processes like image compression but would I create a completely new app/worker to do super simple things like update a field in a database at 10pm every night or send an invoice at the end of the month to my subcribers. If I have 10 super small jobs like sending a nightly email or updating a field, it seems like an overkill to store all those as separate apps.

Comment: @joethemow -- really up to you -- you can do it as one tool.  I think your design should support having different services in the db model -- but how you implement it is up to you.  Leading practices right now is micro -- lots of little applications that do little jobs.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an existing solution. For example temporal.io. See https://docs.temporal.io/workflows#schedule